# What function cum() in pine script is?

Tags: pine-script, mql4

I'm trying to understand `cum()` function on pine script, is there another way to code the same thing without using cum function? I'm trying to get similar code in mql4, but I only need to understand what `cum` does with an example code.

Answer (score 1):

`cum` function return the cumulative sum of the numeric variable from all bars of the series.

You can reproduce the function with a for loop, pseudo code:

```
        for (int bar = 0; bar < series.Length; bar++)
        {
            cum += series[bar];
            return cum;
        }
```